# Is my Surface Pro 3 hard drive dead or can I fix it?

Tags: boot, windows-10, uefi, microsoft-surface-pro-3

Last week my Surface Pro 3 froze. I had to shut it down by holding the power button. It rebooted but after a couple of minutes it froze again. It did this a few times before eventually only booting into the UEFI screen.

I downloaded the appropriate recovery software from Microsoft and used a USB flash drive. However, every reset or recovery option fails to find the hard drive. I also downloaded the Media Creation Tool from Microsoft and created a Windows 10 Installation USB, (My desktop PC and Surface Pro both use Windows 10 Pro 64bit) but I get the same results. The file explorer only shows the USB and not the internal SSD.

I found someone who described the exact same problem and procedures that I have gone through on the Microsoft Community pages. He even supplies handy screen grabs. Frustratingly, a conclusion was never posted. You can read it here...

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/errors-unable-to-reset-your-pc-a-required-drive/b342c634-47d5-469a-92da-089912a9d5f3?auth=1

You can see my recent post at the bottom where I ask how I can boot into a desktop without the internal drive. I'm not sure if I will ever get a reply.

Does anyone know if there is something I can do? Or is my Surface dead?

Thanks

Comment: A Surface Pro 3 doe not have a HDD.  Do you mean the SSD?  Even if the SSD is dead, which is not likely since the lifespan of the SSD in the SP3, even with heavy usage is  several years.  Of course components fail within their expected lifespan all the time.  If the device is within warranty you should make a warranty claim, if it is outside of warranty, and there is a hardware problem you are out of luck.  The SP3 has a very low amount of components that can even be replaced by even the most skilled technician.

Comment: Yes, I do mean the SSD. Unfortunately the warranty ended back in December. Is there any other method I could use to find out if the SSD is still working or accessible even though neither the Recovery USB or Windows installer files can see it?

Comment: The SDD is not user replaceable.  You pretty much have proven the SDD is shot though.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Well, this is annoying. Less than two years of use and now it's an expensive paperweight.